# How to write files in /system (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How to write files in /system folders in Android. Maybe some lines in manifest? And can it collapse the OS (i mean even if the changes will be safe)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't without rooting.  You don't have permissions for that directory.  If you're ok with a rooted only app, you need to be run as root to have permissions.

Note that some phones may have system mounted as read-only.  In that case you'd need to remount it as read-write to write to it, something you can do with mount if you're root.

Writing system in general is safe, but if you overwrite the wrong file you could brick the device or break other apps.  Do so carefully.